# Convert hex+characters to characters

Tags: java, html, dom, escaping, decode

I want to convert a string like this which contains both hexcode and normal characters into characters in Java.
The example input is \x3e\x3c/style\x3e\x3cscript\x3e\x3c!

The output should be `><style><script><`!

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to try.  It's not quite a one liner because URLDecoder.decode wants to throw an exception.

```
import java.net.URLDecoder;

public class TestDecode {


    public void run() throws Exception {
        String test = "\\x3e\\x3c/style\\x3e\\x3cscript\\x3e\\x3c!";
        System.out.printf("%s\n", URLDecoder.decode(test.replaceAll("\\\\x", "%"), "UTF-8"));
    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestDecode td = new TestDecode();
        td.run();
    }
}
```

Output when run is:

```
></style><script><!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot It worked.The only thing left is the input is actually \x3e\x3c/style\x3e\x3cscript\x3e\x3c!.Not \\.Hence its not a proper string.How can I add an additional \ while taking it as input.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add the extra backslash if you're reading that string from an input.  The extra backslash was needed to create the string constant because Java syntax for strings requires it.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is

```
x = '\x3e\x3c/style\x3e\x3cscript\x3e\x3c!'
```

then use

```
x.decode('string_escape')
```

Comment: no the string is \x3e\x3c/style\x3e\x3cscript\x3e\x3c! and the output should be ><style><script><!

Comment: One Line of input is "callbackProxy({"7103/usatoday/high_impact/entertainment/main":{"_type_":"html","_expandable_":false,"_html_":"\x3chtml\x3e\x3chead\x3e\x3cstyle\x3e\x3c!--\na:link {".Here the \ needs to be replace with \\ and " with \" before assigning to string.

Comment: This is a different question now.  Try parsing the input into fields.

Comment: Ask it as a different question on StackOverflow, and show the code you have tried that didn't work.